# FB.ui opens a blank pop-up

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook

I use this code in my angular controller to open the fb share pop-up:

```
$scope.share = function(title,img,description) {
    var title2 = encodeURIComponent(title.trim);
        FB.ui(
            {
                    method: 'feed',
                    name: title,
                    link: 'http://dittadepner.ro/#/pagArticol/'+title2,
                    picture: 'http://dittadepner.ro/uploads/'+img,
                    caption: title,
                    description: description,
                    message: ''
            }, function(response){});
}
```

But when the pop-up opens it's blank.

Comment: Check your developer console.

Comment: If you are talking about the console in the browser it does not say anything related to it...

Comment: Yes, browser console. Apologies. Nothing in the network tab being called from facebook? If not, you need to check the FB library inclusion... though the window may not have even opened. Check the console of the new window.

Comment: that one says something about facebook hacking ... a warning banner put by them but that's it.. can it be because of the "#" sign in the link  ?

Comment: and if I use method share I get a error please try again later message

Comment: I can't reach that link, I get a timeout... maybe that's why. Try a different URL such as Google for testing.

Comment: and something else I've found if I use href instead of link, the link gets ignored and the pop-up opens with data but instead of linking the post to the link it links it with the picture link

Comment: What device are you opening this Feed from?